# How to put boxes around alpha values in legend for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, alpha

I want to put black boxes around the alpha values in the legend, so the smallest value (70) actually shows up. To be clear: around each individual square representing each alpha value, not around the whole legend.

```
mtcars
test_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = mtcars, 
             aes(x = wt, y = mpg,
                 alpha = disp,
                 size = hp), 
             fill = 'black',
             shape = 21) + 
  geom_point(data = mtcars, 
             aes(x = cyl, y = mpg,
                 size = hp), 
             fill = 'black',
             shape = 1) +
  xlab("Weight") + ylab("MPG") + 
  labs(size = "Horsepower:", alpha = "Displacement:") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1,10), breaks= c(50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350)) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0,1), 
                         breaks= c(71.1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500), 
                         labels = c(70, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500)) +
  guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 1)),
         alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 22, color = 'black')))

test_plot
```

[Example of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7QFS.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `alpha` value is both applied to the `fill` of the legend key and the border `color`. Unfortunately I'm not aware of an easy solution to this. One approach to get your desired result is by manipulating the `gtable`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = mtcars, 
             aes(x = wt, y = mpg,
                 alpha = disp,
                 size = hp), 
             fill = 'black',
             shape = 21) + 
  geom_point(data = mtcars, 
             aes(x = cyl, y = mpg,
                 size = hp), 
             fill = 'black',
             shape = 1) +
  xlab("Weight") + ylab("MPG") + 
  labs(size = "Horsepower:", alpha = "Displacement:") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1,10), breaks= c(50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350)) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0,1), 
                         breaks= c(71.1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500), 
                         labels = c(70, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500)) +
  guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 1)),
         alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 22, color = 'black')))

library(gtable)
library(grid)

g <- ggplotGrob(p)
for (i in c(4, 6, 8, 10, 12)) { # Indices of legend keys
  # guide-box is element 15 in the gtable
  # alpha legend if the first element of the "guide-box"
  gp <- g$grobs[[15]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[i]]$gp
  gp <- modifyList(gp, list(col = "black"))
  
  g$grobs[[15]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[i]]$gp <- do.call(grid::gpar, gp)
}
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Map the variable to `fill` instead of `alpha`, with some shape that has an edge, and use `scale_fill_gradient*` with colors varying in alpha. Use `stroke` to control the size of the border.

I simplified your example to highlight the relevant points of the code:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = disp), shape = 21, size = 10, stroke = 1e-10) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = alpha("black", 0), high = alpha("black", 1),  guide = "legend") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 6, stroke = .5)))
```

[image]